# How to change Render Properties on multiple scenes at once?

Tags: scene

I am using EEVEE. I have 36 scenes blended together in other scene (with just VideoSeqenceEditor) to get fade-in animations between collections (in one scene a collection is disabled, in other scene the collection is active, changing opacity of the second scene will give us fade in/out effect without unwanted X-Ray effect).

[image]

Now I want to work on visual aspect, but I don't know how I can change Ambient Occlusion values in Render Properties for all scenes - **without need to enter each scene end change individual values of Ambient Occlusion**.

How to do so?

Comment: maybe an add-on can do this or you write a python script